# Access nested JSON values in AngularJS 2 in template

Tags: json, templates, angular, typescript

I am new to angular 2. How do I get nested data from JSON into my Template?

Here's my JSON:

```
[
    {
        "eId" : "1",
        "name":"Jimi Hendrix", 
        "designation":"UI Developer", 
        "profileImage":"../defaultDP.jpeg", 
        "skills":"HTML, CSS, JS, jQuery, AngularJS, XML", 
        "graph" : {
            "keys" : ["HTML, JS, jQuery, AngularJS"],
            "values" : ["8, 5, 8, 6"]
        }
    }

]
```

And in my template when I am trying to access name, eId I can access easily. e.g,

```
{{JSONDummyData.eId}} {{JSONDummyData.name}}
```

but when I am trying to get Nested values, e.g,

```
{{JSONDummyData.graph.values}}
```

I am not able to access this. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since `keys` and `values` are arrays, you have to specify which element you want to display exactly like so for instance:

```
{{ JSONDummyData.graph.values[0] }}
```

---

> working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tDVABR4N4ZjUPpQlLD5K?p=preview) for example usage

Comment: Then your object does not have the structure you posted.

Comment: Its the same one. :)

Comment: Check out this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/tDVABR4N4ZjUPpQlLD5K?p=preview